# Listener Losing Reference to "this" - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following class that initializes a canvas element for mouse events.  The listeners are initialized in the constructor but when I call `findxy` when the event is fired, the references to variables like `this.flag` result in an error because they are undefined which leads me to believe the listener is losing its reference to `this` when calling `findxy`. I'm not entirely sure how to fix this. Thanks in advance.

```js
class Signature {
  constructor() {
    this.signed = false;
    this.prevX = 0;
    this.currX = 0;
    this.prevY = 0;
    this.currY = 0;
    this.dot_flag = false;
    this.flag = false;
    this.canvas = document.getElementById('can');

    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.w = this.canvas.width;
    this.h = this.canvas.height;

    this.canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", function(e) {
      mobilexy('move', e)
    }, false);
    
    this.canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", function(e) {
      mobilexy('down', e)
    }, false);
    
    this.canvas.addEventListener("touchleave", function(e) {
      mobilexy('up', e)
    }, false);

    this.canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
      findxy('move', e)
    }, false);
    
    this.canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
      findxy('down', e)
    }, false);
    
    this.canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {
      findxy('up', e)
    }, false);
    
    this.canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function(e) {
      findxy('out', e)
    }, false);

    findxy(res, e) {
      if (res == 'down') {
        this.prevX = this.currX;
        this.prevY = this.currY;
        this.currX = e.pageX - this.canvas.offsetLeft;
        this.currY = e.pageY - this.canvas.offsetTop;

        this.flag = true;
        this.dot_flag = true;
        
        if (this.dot_flag) {
          this.ctx.beginPath();
          this.ctx.fillStyle = x;
          this.ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
          this.ctx.closePath();
          this.dot_flag = false;
        }
      }
      
      if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
        this.flag = false;
      }
      
      if (res == 'move') {
        if (this.flag) {
          this.prevX = this.currX;
          this.prevY = this.currY;
          this.currX = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
          this.currY = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
          draw();
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

My error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: flag is not defined
>       at findxy (jobs.self-09776d4c973306a740403ee614a19882dd0d4d402c0c72bba61747ef44c6ab2b.js?body=1:191)
>       at HTMLCanvasElement. (signature.self-e4f9a6f8d0069a7e6488dd64f3234fbdf4b0c2004f9de362da627d0176111f06.js?body=1:31)
>       findxy @ jobs.self-09776d4c973306a740403ee614a19882dd0d4d402c0c72bba61747ef44c6ab2b.js?body=1:191
>       (anonymous) @ signature.self-e4f9a6f8d0069a7e6488dd64f3234fbdf4b0c2004f9de362da627d0176111f06.js?body=1:31
>       09:37:56.162

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scope does not transfer with calls. You need to either pass the `this` reference as an argument:

```
this.canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
  findxy('out', e, this)
}, false); 

findxy(res, e, _this) {
  // call it something more appropriate than '_this' - this is just an example
  _this.prevY = ...;
}
```

Or use `call()` to provide a scope:

```
this.canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
  findxy.call(this, 'out', e)
}, false);
```

Or use jQuery's alternative to `call()`, which is `$.proxy()`:

```
this.canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
  $.proxy(findxy, this, 'out', e)();
}, false);
```

Comment: I tried all three methods. The first doesn't seem to do anything. I'm not sure why, but I can't even get a `console.log("test");` to print out at the beginning of `findxy`. The other methods produced the same error as indicated in the question.

Comment: If `flag` is causing the error but the other methods aren't (eg. `prevX`, `currX` etc.) then I would suggest you `console.log(this)` in the `findxy()` to determine exactly what's being passed is what you expect it to be. Note that within the event handlers, `this` will be the element which raised the event, not your `Signature` class, if that was your intention